# I am trying to rename shapefile with date (.format)

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hello I am getting error for this code I couldn't find the problem

```
Error:
File "C:\Schedule\open_restaurants.py", line 74
    txtFileNameNoExt = "{}_{}".format(os.path.splitext(txtFileNameWithExt)[0], datetime.datetime.now(%y_%m_%d))
                                                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```
#rename shapefile
txtFileNameWithExt = "Open_Restaurants.shp"
txtFileNameNoExt = "{}_{}".format(os.path.splitext(txtFileNameWithExt)[0], datetime.datetime.now(%y_%m_%d))
arcpy.env.workspace = my_Path
arcpy.Rename_management(txtFileNameWithExt,"{}.shp".format(txtFileNameNoExt))
```

Comment: `%y_%m_%d` isn't a timezone object.

Comment: Use `datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%y_%m_%d')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change datetime part to

```
datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%y_%m_%d')
```

docs: [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: what error are you getting? what is  `arcpy` there? is `my_Path` defined?